# How to change the font size of preview options  when using an input method?

Tags: fonts, accessibility, ibus, input-method

I'm using IBus for pinyin in 11.10. A previous AskUbuntu poster mentioned that s/he increased font size to 14 point in Preferences. I'm unable to find a setting in Preferences that allows me to do that.

The Chinese characters in the preview box are way too small and barely legible now.

Just to be clear, this is not about the Chinese text produced in an application program, it is specifically about the size of the five "candidate" Chinese characters that ibus offers me for selection.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the late answer, I am on  this computer only once a week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the *Keybord Input Methods* settings application.

   [image: Screenshot of searching the "Ubuntu Dash" for Keyboard Input Methods]
2. Wait for the settings window to appear. In the "Font and Style" section of the "General" tab, enable the "Use a custom font" checkbox. You can then change the typeface and size of the input preview font with the button to the right.

   [image: Screenshot highlighting the "set custom font" button]

Comment: On Debian Stretch, in Maté, with IBus v. 1.5.14-2, I do not see any difference no matter what custom font-size I use in IBus Preferences. It also seems to make no difference what input method I am using.

Answer (score 0):

#### New Answer for GNOME 3

I was confused by the previous answer because the option is still there, it just doesn’t have any effect by default. There is an extra step you need to do:

1. Install the [ibus font setting](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1121/ibus-font-setting/) extension for GNOME. If you don’t know how to install extensions, see [here](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/install-gnome-extensions-on-ubuntu).
2. Configure the extension to open the font setting dialogue *or* launch the traditional IBus Preferences. For the latter, I had to run the terminal command `ibus-setup` since this application doesn’t show up in my app launcher for some reason.

[image: ibus font setting]