# How to increase font size of preview options when using an input method?

Tags: fonts, 18.04, ibus, accessibility, input-method

I am using `IBus` for `pinyin` in Ubuntu 18.04 (Gnome), with the *"intelligent pinyin"* input method.

The Chinese characters in the preview box are way too small and barely legible, i.e.:

[image]

What I tried:

```
~$ ibus-setup
~$ # I ticked option "Use custom font" and set very large font size
~$ ibus restart                        # (rebooting the machine also has no effect)
```

This did not change the font of the characters in the preview box.

---

**NOTE (not a duplicate):** the troubleshooting I followed is similar to the one proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113021/how-to-change-the-font-size-of-preview-options-when-using-an-input-method) for a previous version of Ubuntu (11.10). The approach described in the previous Q/A does not seem to be valid any longer, so I made a new question because this issue deserves some renewed attention. It is perhaps worth mentioning that the same troubleshooting was working on the most recent `Linux Mint+Cinammon` release, so the issue seems to be related with `Ubuntu+Gnome`.

Comment: Have you checked out if that method to increase the font size is effective with some other input method, e.g. `ibus-sunpinyin`?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I tried several ones for Chinese language, and all of them display the same font size for the preview box. Actually, I suspect that `ibus-setup` configuration is not really being used by the OS, since when I add some new input-method through system settings this is not listed under `ibus-setup`. The thing is, system settings does not show any option to change the font size *AFAIK*.

Comment: I tried your step and it worked.  I'm using version 1.5.22, you may use `ibus version` to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this bug:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1409121

with the advice to install this extension:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1121/ibus-font-setting/

Comment: That's neat, 謝謝!

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, and thank-you to https://extensions.gnome.org/accounts/profile/epico for creating the extension. On a high-res / high-DPI setup, the suggestions would truly be useless without this fix, because the default font size ends up being so small.